# how to select a property depending another property - mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose`. I want to select `users` property depending on another property at this here `type`.

for example when my `type` is `private` I want to select `users`.

```
Conversation.find({
users: {
$elemMatch: {
user: _id
  }
 }
},{
 title: 1,
 type: 1,
 users:1 // when `type` is `private` I want to this field to be one.
});
```

my Schema:

```
const ConversationSchema = new Schema({
    type: {type: String, enum: ['private', 'group'], default: 'private'},
    creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true, required: true}, // creator
    // for group,
    title: String, 
    picture: String,
    description: String,
    users: [
        {
            user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, index: true, reuqired:  true, unique: true }, 
            role: { type: String, enum: ['admin', 'member'], default: 'member' },
            mute: { type:  Boolean, default: false },
            type: {type: String, enum: ['private', 'group'], default: 'private'},
        }
    ],
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: Hi, can you share your schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [conditionally exclude fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#remove-example) by using [REMOVE](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.REMOVE) in aggregation. In your case, it should be:

```
Conversation.aggregate([
  {$match: {"users.user": id}},
  {
     $project: {
       title: 1,
       type: 1,
       users: {
         $cond: { 
           if: { $eq: [ "$type", "private" ] }, 
           then: "$users", 
           else: "$$REMOVE" 
         }
       }
     }
  }
])
```

*Side note*: If you specify only a single  condition in the `$elemMatch` expression, you do not need to use `$elemMatch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate like this, it will select all users if you want to users detail then will have to use populate.

```
db.getCollection("Conversation").aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$users"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "type": 'private'
        }
    }
]);
```