# MongoDB - How to select field if specific condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I want to include and exclude some fields if specific condition in query.**

```
// Survey Schema:
new mongoose.Schema({
    options: {
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.String]
    },
    votes: {
        type: [{
            user: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            option: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number,
        }]
    },
})
```

*And I want some like this in my route handler.*

```
const userID = req.user.id
const isAuth = userID!=undefined

const surveys = await Survey.aggregate([
    $project:{
       options:1,
       votes: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
                 $in: [user.id, 'votes']
            }
          }
       }  
    }
])
```

**And the result should be**

if userID is in the array `votes` for the specific document in the snapshot, the fields should be

```
{options:[], votes:[]},...
```

else

```
{options:[]},...
```

Comment: Are you using `aggregate` just to achieve this?

Comment: Not needed but do you have another idea ?

Comment: Let me write an answer for you.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038708/11711316

Answer (score 1):

If `userID` is `undefined` then set `votes` to 0.

```
let project = {};

if (!userID) {
    project.votes = 0;
}

const surveys = await Survey.find({}, project);
```